# Django-Rest-Framework updating a foreign key BY Id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-framework to build out the back end.  I have the list running fine, but (using the django-rest-framework admin screen) I cannot create an object by just using the Id fields of the foreign key objects.  I hope I have this configured incorrectly,  but I am open to writing some code if i have to :)  I am learning django/python from a .NET and Java background and may have become a touch spoiled by this new stack.

**Edit: I am trying not to use two different Model classes- I shouldn't have to right?**

Thanks in advance.

From Chrome - the key bits of the request

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/favorite_industries/ 
Request Method:POST 
_content_type:application/json
_content:{
    "user_id": 804    ,"industry_id": 20 }
```

The response

```
HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Ugh.  Here are the key classes from django:

```
class FavoriteIndustry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='favorite_industries')
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'favorites_mas_industry'

class FavoriteIndustrySerializer(WithPkMixin, serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = myModels.FavoriteIndustry
        fields = (
            'id'
            , 'user'
            , 'industry'
        )
```

**Edit Adding the viewset:**

```
class FavoriteIndustriesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    paginate_by = 1
    queryset = myModels\
        .FavoriteIndustry\
        .objects\
        .select_related()
    print 'SQL::FavoriteIndustriesViewSet: ' + str(queryset.query)
    serializer_class = mySerializers.FavoriteIndustrySerializer
```

The get/list functionality generates decent JSON:

> {"count": 2, "next":
>   "http://blah.com/rest/favorite_industries/?page=2&format=json",
>   "previous": null, "results": [{"id": 1, "user":
>   "http://blah.com/rest/users/804/", "industry": {"industry_id":
>   2, "industry_name": "Consumer Discretionary", "parent_industry_name":
>   "Consumer Discretionary", "category_name": "Industries"}}]}

Comment: Please share the view code you are using for the API.

Comment: It is shared that's all the code I am using django-rest-framework.  Wait there is the viewSet but I don't see how it is important.  Basically the url is routed to the viewSet and the REST is magic :)

Comment: Have you tried passing `user` instead of `user_id`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have created a simplified mock up of your application.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class FavoriteIndustry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='favorite_industries')
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry)
```

**views.py:**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from models import FavoriteIndustry
from serializers import FavoriteIndustrySerializer

class FavoriteIndustriesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FavoriteIndustry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FavoriteIndustrySerializer
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import FavoriteIndustry, Industry

class FavoriteIndustrySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FavoriteIndustry
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'industry')
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from core.api import FavoriteIndustriesViewSet

favorite_industries_list = FavoriteIndustriesViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^favorite_industries/$', favorite_industries_list, name='favorite-industries-list'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', favorite_industries_list, name='user-detail'),
    url(r'^industries/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', favorite_industries_list, name='industry-detail'),
)
```

And here are a few tests:

```
>>> 
>>> import json
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> from core.models import Industry
>>> 
>>> industry = Industry(name='candy')
>>> industry.save()
>>> 
>>> c = Client()
>>> 
>>> response = c.get('http://localhost:8000/favorite_industries/')
>>> response.content
'[]'
>>> 
>>> data = {
...     'user': 'http://localhost:8000/users/1/',
...     'industry': 'http://localhost:8000/industries/1/'
... }
>>> 
>>> response = c.post('http://localhost:8000/favorite_industries/', json.dumps(data), 'application/json')
>>> response.content
'{"id": 1, "user": "http://testserver/users/1/", "industry": "http://testserver/industries/1/"}'
>>> 
>>> response = c.get('http://localhost:8000/favorite_industries/')
>>> response.content
'[{"id": 1, "user": "http://testserver/users/1/", "industry": "http://testserver/industries/1/"}]'
>>>
```

Django REST Framework expects `user` and `industry` fields as URLs rather than ids since you are using `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.

---

## Using IDs

In case you need to use object ids instead of URLs, use `ModelSerializer` instead of `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and pass ids to `user` and `industry`:

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import FavoriteIndustry, Industry

class FavoriteIndustrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FavoriteIndustry
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'industry')
```

And tests:

```
>>> 
>>> import json
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> from core.models import Industry
>>> 
>>> #industry = Industry(name='candy')
>>> #industry.save()
>>> 
>>> c = Client()
>>> 
>>> response = c.get('http://localhost:8000/favorite_industries/')
>>> response.content
'[{"id": 1, "user": 1, "industry": 1}, {"id": 2, "user": 1, "industry": 1}]'
>>> 
>>> data = {
...     'user': 1,
...     'industry': 1
... }
>>> 
>>> response = c.post('http://localhost:8000/favorite_industries/', json.dumps(data), 'application/json')
>>> response.content
'{"id": 3, "user": 1, "industry": 1}'
>>> 
>>> response = c.get('http://localhost:8000/favorite_industries/')
>>> response.content
'[{"id": 1, "user": 1, "industry": 1}, {"id": 2, "user": 1, "industry": 1}, {"id": 3, "user": 1, "industry": 1}]'
>>>
```

Comment: I am not actually following the Hyperlinks from the HyperlinkSerializer therefore I wonder if there is a better serializer to use.  There is probably some reading to do on my end.

Comment: Updated answer with a `ModelSerializer` approach.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! If this could be updated to read "views.py:" instead of "urls.py" for the code snipped containing "class FavoriteIndustriesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):", that would be very helpful. Otherwise, great post.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.  But I think the django-rest-framework should provide this plumbing for me, so please follow up with any *better* answers

```
class FavoriteIndustriesViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    paginate_by = 1
    queryset = myModels\
        .FavoriteIndustry\
        .objects\
        .select_related()
    print 'SQL::FavoriteIndustriesViewSet: ' + str(queryset.query)
    serializer_class = mySerializers.FavoriteIndustrySerializer

    def create(self, request):
        print(request.DATA)
        user_id = request.DATA['user_id']
        industry_id = request.DATA['industry_id']
        favorite = myModels.FavoriteIndustry(user_id=user_id, industry_id=industry_id)
        favorite.save()
        responseData = {
            'user_id': user_id
            , 'industry_id': industry_id
            , 'message': 'FavoriteIndustry saved.'
        }
        return Response(responseData)
```

Comment: You are solving a problem that you have created. Passing `user_id` and `industry_id` is the main issue, this implementation of yours works the way you want, but that's not how DRF works out of the box. Pass `user` and `industry` if you want to see magic.

Comment: "I see", said the blind man.  I don't have the user object stored on the client, I do have the user_id persisted.

Comment: You don't need the actual object, you need to pass the URL to that object since you are using `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`, i.e. `"user": "http://blah.com/rest/users/804/"`