# Django Rest Framework: Specifying a OneToOneField by ID when creating an object via ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having some trouble creating an object with a OneToOneField reference by ID. Example of my code:

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(length=50)


class ExtraInfo(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        Person,
        related_name='+',
        primary_key=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    info = models.CharField(length=50)
```

serializers.py

```
class ExtraInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ExtraInfo
```

views.py

```
class ExtraInfoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.ExtraInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ExtraInfoSerializer
```

urls.py

```
...
api_router = DefaultRouter()
api_router.register(r'extrainfo', ExtraInfoView)

url_patterns = [
    url(r'/', include(api_router.urls))
]
...
```

Now, whenever I do a GET /extrainfo/ I get something along the lines of:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "person": 1,
            "info": "foo"
        },
        {
            "person": 2,
            "info": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

So this is all good - exactly what I expect. The issue comes when I try to create some ExtraInfo, when I POST to /extrainfo/ with a body such as:

```
{
    "person": 3,
    "info": "blah"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "3": "ExtraInfo.person" must be a "Person" instance.
```

So I understand what it's saying - if I was doing this in bespoke code I would want to do something like ExtraInfo.objects.create(person_id=3, info="blah"). I just can't figure out how to get it to behave like I want.

I have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414405/6610756) and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I seem to be able to work around it by adding this to my serializer:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data['person_id'] = validated_data['person']
    del validated_data['person']
    return super(ExtraInfoSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

But this doesn't seem like the best way to do it. I feel like I've either missed something small, or am fundamentally misunderstanding something, but either way I find it strange that it will serialize to the primary key for the GET but won't use it similarly in the POST. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The serializer expect the `person` to be model instance, so you could do:

```
{
    "person": Person.objects.get(pk=3),
    "info": "blah"
}
```

In the view you get the firs-order representation of related model instance, which is its primary key. You could also get the complete model instance by specifying the depth parameter in serializer. Like:

```
class ExtraInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ExtraInfo
        depth = 1
```

Comment: The POST body is JSON, it's not Python code - one can't call Person.objects.get in it.

Comment: This issue might be caused by `related_name=+`. If possibly define it something else (eg. `related_name='extra_info') or leave it undefined so that it takes default value. This might have interfered in the linking process. Does it help?

Comment: Hmm, no it doesn't seem to make a difference.